# Added 0 in output file not visible in console

Tags: c

I am trying to understand why I am having a zero added on to one of my variables userNumberInput. I have been trying to figure out why this is happening for the a bit without a good solution or explanation. It is only happening in the output file, and does not appear to be happening as a result of the variable being set to 0.

For example if you enter 90 the console shows 90, but the output file shows 900.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void Fibonacci (int userInputNumber);
void UserInput (int* userInputNumber);

FILE *fpOut;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
//Creating global variable for userInput to be passed from function to function
int userInputNumber = 0;

//Opening file for writing output to
if (!(fpOut = fopen("csis.txt", "w"))) {
    printf("csis.text could not be opened for output");
    exit(1);
}

//Calling two functions and passing appropriate vaiables to each
UserInput(&userInputNumber);
Fibonacci(userInputNumber);

fclose(fpOut);
return 0;
}

void UserInput (int* userInputNumber) {
//Asks the user for a number for the generator
printf("Enter a number into the Fibonacci Generator: ");
scanf("%d", &*userInputNumber);
fprintf(fpOut,"Enter a number into the Fibonacci Generator: %d", *userInputNumber);

//While the user continues to enter a negative number it forces the user to enter a new number
while (*userInputNumber < 0) {
    printf("Invalid user input, enter a positive number\n\n");
    fprintf(fpOut,"Invalid user input, enter a positive number\n\n");
    printf("Enter a number into the Fibonacci Generator: ");
    scanf("%d", &*userInputNumber);
    fprintf(fpOut,"Enter a number into the Fibonacci Generator: %d", *userInputNumber);
}
}

void Fibonacci (int userInputNumber) {
//Defines variables used in this function
int firstNumber, secondNumber, i, seriesNumber, length;
firstNumber = 0;
secondNumber = 1;
seriesNumber = 0;
i = 0;
length = 0;

//For loop that adds the two previous number in the series and prints it and then updates the previous numbers
for (i = 0; seriesNumber < userInputNumber; i++) {
    if (i <= 1) {
        seriesNumber = i;
        length++;
    } else {
        seriesNumber = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        firstNumber = secondNumber;
        secondNumber = seriesNumber;
        length++;
    }

    //Statement to break the loop when the next number in the series goes above the user input
    if (seriesNumber > userInputNumber) {
        length -= 1;
        break;
    }

    //Printing the sequence
    printf("%d\n",seriesNumber);
    fprintf(fpOut,"%d\n",seriesNumber);
}

//Printing the length of the sequence
printf("Length of the sequence: %d", length);
fprintf(fpOut,"Length of the sequence: %d", length);
}
```

Comment: Please show your full test run and contents of output file. I'm suspecting the 0 is coming from the first output in the `Fibonacci` function being tacked onto the end of the `UserInput` output since the latter does not have a `\n` at the end of it.

Comment: `&*userInputNumber` probably not related to your problem but that's just a weird way of coding. It should be just `userInputNumber`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print a newline after printing the value entered, or `0`, which is the first term of the sequence, seems to be appended to the input.

Try changing both of the two

```
fprintf(fpOut,"Enter a number into the Fibonacci Generator: %d", *userInputNumber);
```

to

```
fprintf(fpOut,"Enter a number into the Fibonacci Generator: %d\n", *userInputNumber);
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for this! Makes total sense. I knew it was a silly mistake likely, but I thought it had something to do with me setting userNumberInput to 0. Thanks a million!